# How to use EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART with WinEventProc as global window locationchange/resize event?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, events

I'm trying to catch the move and resize event globally.
I found the way to use the EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART event via Win32 API WinEventProc (actually I'm using C# P/invoke).
But I couldn't find the detail information about it. I have some questions:

- Q1. Is there any way to *distinguish* MOVE or RESIZE when raised EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART event, without polling the window size/location.

  ```
  public static void __WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, Native.EVENT eventType, IntPtr hWnd, Native.OBJID idObject, Native.CHILDID idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
  {
      if (eventType == Native.Event.SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART)
      {
          switch (__something__)
          {
              case __THIS_EVENT_IS_MOVE:
                  doSomethingWhenMoveStarted();
                  break;
              case __THIS_EVENT_IS_RESIZE:
                  doSomethingWhenResizeStarted();
                  break;
  ```

  (IMHO, Windows does not distinguish them internally...?)
- Q2. Is there any event or the way something like EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVINGRESIZING, which raised continuously, like [mousemove event on javascript/DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Events/mousemove)?

If you have an another way to do Q1,Q2, also let me know please!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The event you specified `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART` is sent by the system.

I doubt this event is recognized by `DefWindowProc`.

But during this scenario, I guess the window receives `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`.

Then you can handle in the case statement of your overridden window procedure function.

The `wParam` specifies `SC_MOVE` or `SC_SIZE` value, to identify whether it is **move** or **resize**.

**Below is pseudo code:**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWNd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

   switch (message)
   {
   case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:

    if(wParam == SC_MOVE)
        {
        //MOVE
        }
        else
        {
        //RESIZE
        }     

   default:
    //Call to default winproc
   }

}
```

**As you are saying C#**, there are some events associated to `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` and `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` in  `System.Windows.Forms`. They are `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd`. But I am little unsure if these events can handle `Move`.